# How to convert date in to yyyy-MM-dd Format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

> Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012

I have to convert above date into below format

> 2012-12-01

How can i?

i have tried with following method but its not working

```
public Date ConvertDate(Date date){

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String s = df.format(date);
    String result = s;
    try {
        date=df.parse(result);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
  }
```

Comment: whats is the meaning in this method `public Date ConvertDate(Date date)` ?

Comment: @vels4j its returning the date with the format of yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: @Oded i was just in hurry that's why.sorry about that.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher i dint think it was duplicate.the input format was different so i dint find that link while goggling

Comment: The input in the aforementioned link is a string, and yours is a Date object. looking at the answers below(_and the one you have selected_) I still can't understand how that question doesn't help you.

Comment: Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012 i am talking about this input format.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. A `Date` hasn’t got a format. You can have your desired format only in a `String` outside the `Date`. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use this.

```
java.util.Date date = new Date("Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String format = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(format);
```

you will get the output as

```
2012-12-01
```

Comment: +1 and new Date() method is deprecated. must use Calendar instead

Comment: @vels4j Why don't you share the code to use Calendar for the replacement of deprecated constructor for Date?

Answer (score 4):

```
String s;
Format formatter;
Date date = new Date();

// 2012-12-01
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
s = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** My Answer here is now outdated. The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, advising migration to the *java.time* classes. See the modern solution in the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48380210/642706).

## Joda-Time

The accepted answer by [NidhishKrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14039210/642706) is correct.

For fun, here is the same kind of code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

java.util.Date date = new Date(); // A Date object coming from other code.

// Pass the java.util.Date object to constructor of Joda-Time DateTime object.
DateTimeZone kolkataTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeInKolkata = new DateTime( date, kolkataTimeZone );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println( "dateTimeInKolkata formatted for date: " + formatter.print( dateTimeInKolkata ) );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInKolkata formatted for ISO 8601: " + dateTimeInKolkata );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInKolkata formatted for date: 2013-12-17
dateTimeInKolkata formatted for ISO 8601: 2013-12-17T14:56:46.658+05:30
```

Answer (score 3):

Modern answer: Use `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and its `toString` method:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2012, Month.DECEMBER, 1); // get from somewhere
    String formattedDate = date.toString();
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

This prints

> 2012-12-01

A date (whether we’re talking `java.util.Date` or `java.time.LocalDate`) doesn’t have a format in it. All it’s got is a `toString` method that produces some format, and you cannot change the `toString` method. Fortunately, `LocalDate.toString` produces exactly the format you asked for.

The `Date` class is long outdated, and the `SimpleDateFormat` class that you tried to use, is notoriously troublesome. I recommend you forget about those classes and use `java.time` instead. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

Except: it happens that you get a `Date` from a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now. The best thing you can do with it is convert it to `java.time.Instant` and do any further operations from there:

```
    Date oldfashoinedDate = // get from somewhere
    LocalDate date = oldfashoinedDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Beirut"))
            .toLocalDate();
```

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Asia/Beirut. Then proceed as above.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't format the `Date` itself. You can only get the formatted result in `String`. Use `SimpleDateFormat` as mentioned by others.

Moreover, most of the `getter methods in Date` are `deprecated.`

Answer (score 0):

A date-time object is supposed to store the information about the date, time, timezone etc., **not about the formatting**. You can format a date-time object into a **`String`** with the pattern of your choice using date-time formatting API.

- The date-time formatting API for the modern date-time types is in the package, `java.time.format` e.g. `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` etc.
- The date-time formatting API for the legacy date-time types is in the package, `java.text` e.g. `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, `java.text.DateFormat` etc.

**Demo using modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.DECEMBER, 1).atStartOfDay(),
                ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

        // Default format returned by Date#toString
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedDate = dtf.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2012-12-01T00:00Z[Europe/London]
2012-12-01
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Demo using legacy API:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        // Default format returned by Date#toString
        System.out.println(date);

        // Custom format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012
2012-12-01
```

**Some more important points:**

1. The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the milliseconds from the `Epoch of January 1, 1970`. When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time calculated from this milliseconds value. Since `java.util.Date` does not have timezone information, it applies the timezone of your JVM and displays the same. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFomrat` and obtain the formatted string from it.
2. The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

   - For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
   - If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).