# How to convert date formats?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat, date-parsing

So I have this String: "Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 IDT 2014" or "Apr 15 2014" after I change it by split it.
And I want to convert it to this format: "yyyy-MM-dd" but when I i get this message:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Apr 15 2014"
```

Here is my full code:

```
DateFormat or=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy");
            DateFormat tr=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
           String str="Apr 15 2014";

            System.out.println(str);
            //String strs[]=str.split(" ");
            //String newDay=strs[1]+" "+strs[2]+" "+strs[5];
            //System.out.println(newDay);
            try {
                Date d1=or.parse(str);
                System.out.println(d1);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks to helpers :)

Comment: Here is the Solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039062/how-to-convert-date-in-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039062/how-to-convert-date-in-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Comment: Don't use split find the format

Comment: Where do you actually convert it? The parsing works fine for me, prints the correct date (`Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 CEST 2014`). After adding `System.out.println(tr.format(d1));` in your try-catch it prints the correct result: `2014-04-15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The month field value in the input String may not match that from your default `Locale`. Try

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
...
Date date = format.parse(str);
```

Note: Rather than manipulating the original `String` it could have been parsed directly with

```
DateFormat format = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Date getDateFromString(String format, String dateStr) {

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return date;
        }

-----------------

    public static String getDate(Date date, String dateFormat) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change to your code:

```
        **DateFormat or = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");**
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String str = "Apr 15 2014";

    System.out.println(str);
    //String strs[]=str.split(" ");
    //String newDay=strs[1]+" "+strs[2]+" "+strs[5];
    //System.out.println(newDay);
    try {
        Date d1 = or.parse(str);
        System.out.println(d1);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I got the following output:

```
Apr 15 2014
```

`Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 BST 2014`

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date  ss1=new Date("Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 IDT 2014");
SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formats1 = formatter5.format(ss1);
System.out.println(formats1);
```