# convert a list of string list date

Tags: java, arraylist

Good evening everyone!

My form sends a String list in this format:

```
dd/ MM / yyyy
```

Wanted converts this string list in date to the format :

```
yyyy - MM - dd
```

How can I do this in Java ?

Comment: First you need to write some code

Comment: Have a look at this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039062/how-to-convert-date-in-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format

Comment: Look into `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Duplicate: [Parse Date from String in this format : dd/MM/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3386520/642706)

Answer (score 0):

```java
File file = new File("/Users/eclipse-workspace"); // Absolute path
long lastModified = file.lastModified();    // File into lastModifiedDate lastModifiedDate = new Date(lastModified);    //
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  // Display format 
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(lastModifiedDate);     // 
System.out.print("Last Modified Date :"+ formattedDate);    //
```

Comment: But to do it with a List < String> ?
I have a List < String> Xy , this List I will use a "For " to convert each value in Date to enter in my database.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateInString = "your_date";

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);