# How to modify date format?

Tags: java, android

Please help me to find a solution on this issue
This is the date format I got form Json object

```
Sun Jan 08 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017.
```

I need to convert this date format to `2017-01-05`.

I implemented some code like this

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(summary1.getDeliveryDate());
if(date1.equals(df.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date())))
{
       spinnerArray.add("Cancel");
}
```

I am unable to enter in to loop... Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039062/how-to-convert-date-in-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code**

```
    String inputDate = "2017-01-05 00:00:00";
    System.out.println("Input Date: "+inputDate);
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    Date formatDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
    String outputDate = simpleDateFormat.format(formatDate);
    System.out.println("Output Date: " +outputDate);
```

Output :

```
Input Date: 2017-01-05 00:00:00
Output Date: 2017-01-05
```

Please check and let me know.

Comment: when I write like this "    summary1.getDeliverydate()   " I got a date format like this "2017-01-05 00:00:00.0" I want to eliminate this " 00:00:00.0 "

Comment: Please store summary1.getDeliverydate() into a variable and check the datatype of the variable and then applythe above mentioned logic.

Comment: summary1.getDeliverydate() it returns string data type.. I used your code 

String pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String formatDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);

after this code execution i got date format like this 
Sun Jan 08 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017

but I need like this 
2017-01-05

Comment: Check the above code... After execuring "Date formatDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date)" code please use "String outputDate = simpleDateFormat.format(formatDate);" I have already mentioned the code in above . Please use that. You will get the desire output. I have also tested in eclipse.

Comment: Please execute the code like this - 
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date formatDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
String outputDate = simpleDateFormat.format(formatDate);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you.

```
Date date1 = summary1.getDeliveryDate();
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
if(fmt.format(date1).equals(fmt.format(new Date())))
{
    spinnerArray.add("Cancel");
}
```