# How to convert String yyyy-MM-ssThh-mm-ss to LocalDataTime yyyy-MM-ss hh-mm-ss?

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot, type-conversion

As in title I have a question. I need to parse  LocalDataTime yyyy-MM-ssThh-mm-ss to LocalDataTime yyyy-MM-ss hh-mm-ss but when I do

```
String beforeConversionStartDate = "2020-01-24T00:06:56";
 private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDataTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(beforeConversionStartDate,formatter);
```

Then my output is still yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

So my question is how to remove this "T" from LocalDataTime if parser doesn't work properly?

Comment: How are you printing your output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert date in to yyyy-MM-dd Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039062/how-to-convert-date-in-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing between `parse` and `format` method.

1. First, you want to `parse` your input to a LocalDateTime instance
2. Then, you `format` this instance according to your formatter

   ```
   String beforeConversionStartDate = "2020-01-24T00:06:56";
   LocalDateTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(beforeConversionStartDate);
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   String formattedDate = parsedDate.format(formatter);
   ```

Comment: The point is that the `parsedDate` doesn't have an innate format.  So if you just naively try to print it using `toString()` the *default* format will be used to print it.

Answer (score 0):

[LocalDateTime (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)
This function

```
LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter);
```

takes in a string with formatted in pattern defined by formatter and returns a LocalDateTime Object, however the returned object is unaware of what what formatter was used.
Hence, you will have to format it after you have obtained the parsed your string:

```
    String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
    String newDateTime = formatter.format(dateTime);
```

Comment: the point is that my input string is with "1986-04-08T 12:30" and as you can see there is a "T" letter between day and hour and I need to remove this T and then parse without T to LocalDataTime with T inside